# Does Autobahn|Python[asyncio] support secure websockets?

Tags: python, autobahn

Does the asyncio variant of Autobahn|Python support secure WebSockets? The docs on secure WebSockets with AutoBahn|Python only give a Twisted example: https://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websocket/examples.html#secure-websocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work. Here is an example of an asyncio component with secure websocket :

```
import ssl
from autobahn.asyncio.component import Component


ssl_c = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_c.load_verify_locations(cafile='my_ssl_key.pem')

Component(
    transports={
            'type': 'websocket',
            'url': u'wss://127.0.0.1:8081/',
            'endpoint': {
                'type': 'tcp',
                'host': host,
                'port': 8081,
                'tls': ssl_c
            }
    },
    realm=u'realm1'
)
```